# SQL Query to Filter a Table using two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have 4 SQL tables that look like this:

CustomersTable, RegistrationTable, OrdersTable and OffersTable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKQc3.png)

I need to write a SELECT statement that retrieves all customers from the CustomersTable (all the fields) that contain rows that match the RegistrationTable Or rows that match the OrdersTable with status "closed", in the result table shouldn't display duplicate customers.

As you realized, CustomersTable and RegistrationTable have the field in common "customerId", but between CustomersTable and OrdersTable there is no field in common. However there is another table (OffersTable) which has the fields "customerId" and "ID", to query information to Customers and Orders table respectively. Remember that a customer who appears in OfferTable not necessarily will appear in OrderTable or just the status is NOT "Closed"

So based on my example tables above, if I were to run the query, it would return the following result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Gy2c.png)

In the result table shouldn't display duplicate customers.
I really appreciate your help.
Thanks for your time !!

Note - I am using MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using "Union" and "inner join" with every table  Like below:

```
 Select Customers.* from Customers inner join Registration on Customers. customerId= Registration.customerId

 union

Select Customers.* from Customers inner join offers on Customers.customerId=offers.customerId 
inner join Orders on orders.Id= offers.Id and Orders.Status='closed'
```

Comment: Thanks, but need to mention that in Orders Table there is no a column customerId. That's why i attached the data in Offers Table. Matching these tables Customers (customerId) - Offers (customerId, ID) - Orders (ID) could work to query from Customers to Orders.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding, I have edited the query to inner join with offers table

Comment: It's fine, thank you for your quick reply. I'll try using this sentence !

Answer (score 0):

I would think `exists` or `in`, given what you want.  Your description of the table is a bit cumbersome -- which is why sample data in the question is so helpful.

The resulting query would look something like this:

```
select c.*
from customers c
where exists (select 1 from registrations r where r.customerid = c.customerid) or
      exists (select 1
              from offers o join
                   orders oo
                   on o.id = oo.orderid
              where o.customerid = c.customerid and
                    oo.status = 'closed'
             );
```

The column names may not be quite right.

Comment: Sorry for the cumbersome issue with my description. The column "orderId" in Orders Table with  column "id" in Offers Table are different type of data. In this case, should use this  "o.id = oo.id"  instead of     "o.id = oo.orderid ", right?

Comment: @KuronoK. . . .That seems like a strange foreign key relationship.  You should edit the question and provide sample data.